# PHP Json output with special character

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using this PHP script

```
<?php
mysql_connect("blabla", "blabla", "blabla") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("blabla") or die(mysql_error());

    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC");


 while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
             $output[]=$e;
       print(json_encode($output));
       mysql_close();
?>
```

The output is Json. In the mySQL database there are entries with "ü,ä, ö" (German)
For entries containing an "ü, ä, ö" the value is "null". I cannot figure out what is the problem with these characters.

Comment: When `json_encode` returns not a string an error occured. Check if it returns `NULL` and handle the error condition. To find out which error happened, use [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).

Comment: Which encoding has the data that comes from the database? Probably the only thing you need to do is to make the connection charset UTF-8.

Comment: in the mysql db "latin1_general_ci" is used

Comment: In the db, okay. And for the connection to the db when you pull the data (mysql changes it on the fly so to meet the database clients expectation (that's your PHP script)).

Comment: I dont get your point. What should I change. Above you can see the PHP code

Comment: Try: `echo mysql_client_encoding();` after the `mysql_connect()` line [ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php) - it will tell you the client encoding use. With `mysql_set_charset('UTF8');` you should be able to change it if it's not UTF8. `json_encode` needs UTF8 encoded data. But add in any case what the echo'ed value is.

Comment: echo mysql_client_encoding() returns latin1. I tried to set "mysql_set_charset('UTF8');" before the mysql_connect() function, it returns me an error: mysql_set_charset() [function.mysql-set-charset]: Access denied for user

Comment: It's just the other way round: the function needs a connection. So first connect, then set the charset.

Comment: ok, thx. This is working. Now I get for entries with a special character like "ä,ü,ö" something like this "F\u00fcr" instead of "Für" How can I convert these hex to character?

Comment: That is valid json, you don't need to convert it. Looks good!

Comment: You are right, in android the output looks well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Call `utf8_encode` on each string value before passing them to `json_encode`.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to realize it. I have added my PHP code above.

Comment: Replace `$output[]=$e;` with `$output[] = is_string($e) ? utf8_encode($e) ? $e;`

Comment: ok, we have to replace the second ? with a :   But I stil get "null" instead of e.g. the word "für"

Comment: Oops, sorry for the typo. Also, I see your elements are arrays. You need a nested solution. Okay, go back to `$output[]=$e;`, and then just before the `print()`, add this code: `array_walk_recursive($output,function(&$a) {if(is_string($a)) $a = utf8_decode($a);});`

Comment: This gives following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/a80/public_html/get.php on line 17

Comment: Okay, you're using an older version of PHP than me. Try this instead: `array_walk_recursive($output,create_function('$a','return is_string($a) ? utf8_encode($a) : $a;'));`

Comment: this code line is running. But I still get no "null" for each entry containing a character "ü, ä, ö". See the comments at my post, perhaps you get there the information which you need to solve the riddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Hade the same issue with swedish charset from php to js via ajax and json, values containing any chars like ÅÄÖ got assigned null. The solution turned out to be fairly simple:

1. Log into php myadmin
2. Change *MySQL connection collation* to utf8_swedish_ci (or your language equivalence, my guess would be utf8_unicode_ci for german but you probably know better).
3. Delete locally stored data such as cache, cookies, and localStorage and wholla it works!

Consequently, the key here is to make sure to set the correct MySQL connection collation in the home page of phpmyadmin (or similar) and repetitively use the same collation throughout your db.